# Package ctags is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: apt

Tried to install ctags for vim to work with and was unable to locate it

`apt-cache search ctags`

`Package ctags is not available, but is referred to by another package`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to enable apt-get source into `/etc/apt/sources.list` uncommenting it
then `apt-get update` and then finally the

`apt-cache search ctags`

gave me

```
cgvg - command-line source browsing tool
codequery - code-understanding, code-browsing or code-search tool
exuberant-ctags - build tag file indexes of source code definitions
geany-plugin-ctags - ctags plugin for Geany
hasktags - Producer of ctags "tags" and etags "TAGS" files for Haskell programs
hothasktags - Haskell ctags generator
libparse-exuberantctags-perl - exuberant ctags parser for Perl
moap - Swiss army knife for project maintainers and developers
```

I could finally install `exuberant-ctags` with `sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags`

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.