# Package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: apt, software-compilation, gcc

I try to compile a piece of software with a pre-defined [Docker-enviroment](https://github.com/brocaar/chirpstack-concentratord/blob/master/Dockerfile-devel), where following packages are getting installed: `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`, `g++-arm-linux-gnueabi`, `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf`. The docker image building fails as it can't get those packages (same error 4x):

```
Package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I already tried to solve it by using [this questions' answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82825/package-ctags-is-not-available-but-is-referred-to-by-another-package) but the error remains the same.  (I also can't install that compiler locally on the pi, so I did that change on the local machine to see if it fixes the problem)

It's a Raspberry Pi 3 (so armv7).
Hope anyone can help me out, as I'm quite new to compiling software! Thank you.

Comment: A search through the packages suggested that `apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
` could solve this (have not tried it; just a suggestion). And you may need to specify the C-compiler as `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v`, otherwise it will use the default (which is probably x86)

Comment: The Dockerfile you're using cross compiles the software. It is meant to be executed on an x86 machine, not on the Pi itself.